# Calling MVC5 action using AXIOS and ValidateAntiForgeryToken

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc-5, axios

I am trying to call a controller method marked with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] from my UI using Axios.

I have successfully called the same action by using Jquery ajax

Working AJAX Code.

First i get the token from my form

```
   var addAntiForgeryToken = function (data) {
            data.__RequestVerificationToken = $("[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
            return data;
        };
```

amd then i call my method

```
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:40428/controller/action",
            data: addAntiForgeryToken({ }),
            success: function (response) {

            }
        });
```

The above successfully calls the following method in my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Test_Get()
    {
        ViewBag.Search = true;
        return View("Index");
    }
```

What i have already tried with axios is the following

```
    axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://localhost:40428/Meeting_Notes/Test_Get',
            data: addAntiForgeryToken({})
        });
```

I have also tried setting the headers manually but I still cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching around for a bit I found a simple solution. First create the controller and decorate it with HttpPost and ValidateAntiForgeryToken

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public void Test_Axios(int id) { }
```

Then before calling the controller using axios add the following interceptor for the headers. This will define the header as default for all axios api calls

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

then retreive the token

```
var token = document.querySelector('token, input').getAttribute('value');
```

then use the qs library to stringify the call with the token (Be careful! it's Qs and not qs!)

```
var request = Qs.stringify({ id: 22, __RequestVerificationToken: token });
```

if you don't wanna pass any parameters then you can just use the following

```
var request = Qs.stringify({ __RequestVerificationToken: token });
```

then just call the controller method

```
axios({
     method: 'post',
     url: "/controller/Test_Axios",
     data: request 
});
```

And you are done! You can now start calling mvc 5 controller, decorated with the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute.